# Using a custom AMI (with s3cmd) in a Datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline

How can I install s3cmd on a AMI that is used in the pipeline?
This should be a fairly basic thing to do but I can't seem to get it done:
Here's what I've tried:

> - Started a Pipeline without the Image-id option => Everything works fine
> - Navigated to EC2 and created an Image of the running Instance to make sure all the needed stuff to run in the pipeline is installed on my custom AMI
> - Started this AMI manually as an Instance
> - SSH'd into the machine and installed S3cmd
> - Created another Image of the machine, this time with s3cmd installed
> - Shut down the Instance
> - Started the Pipeline again, this time with the newly created AMI as Image-id and S3cmd installed

Now the Resource starts "RUNNING" but my Activity (ShellCommandActivity) is stuck in the WAITING_FOR_RUNNER state and the script never gets executed.

What do I have to do to get the pipeline running with a custom image? Or is there even an easier way to use s3cmd in a pipeline?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a step. After you installed s3cmd, did you create a new AMI before you shut down the instance?

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry. Of course I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out now, by using a "clean" Amazon Linux AMI (from the marketplace for example) and installing S3cmd, rather than creating an AMI out of a running Pipeline Resource. I saw that this AMI has a different Kernel version, so this could have been the problem.

Comment: For other things creating AMI might be inevitable, because you can't "sudo" in ShellCommandAcitivity, which limits the things you can install locally through shell script.

Comment: You certainly can `sudo`: `{
      "id" : "ActivityId_Tf7hc",
      "schedule" : { "ref" : "ScheduleId_F94pd" },
      "name" : "InstallDocker",
      "command" : "sudo /bin/bash -c 'yum install -y docker && sed -i \"/hugetlb/d\" /etc/cgconfig.conf && sed -i \"/memory/d\" /etc/cgconfig.conf && service docker start'",
      "runsOn" : { "ref" : "ResourceId_sQCNM" },
      "type" : "ShellCommandActivity"
    }`